# JS: Looping through specific Object props and creating a new Object

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop

The Object that I am looping has several properties like:

```
contentAsset.custom = {
  brandInfoHeader: 'header',
  brandInfoLinkUrl: 'link1',
  brandInfoLinkUrl2 : 'link2'
  brandInfoLinkText: 'text1',
  brandInfoLinkTextLink1 : 'text2' // and many more that I lose count
};
```

I want all the 12 properties (6 of each) that have key brandInfoTextLink and brandInfoLinkUrl. I have a function looping over the obj, but I am not sure how to get these 12 props from sea of props which have different numbers. I can write 12 if statements but that won't be a good practice. function:

```
function loopthru () {
            var obj = {};

                for (var key in contentAsset.custom){
                    obj[key] =  contentAsset.custom[key];
                    }

            return obj;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to find the properties that you want:

```js
var contentAsset = {};
contentAsset.custom = {
  brandInfoHeader: 'header',
  brandInfoLinkUrl: 'link1',
  brandInfoLinkUrl2: 'link2',
  brandInfoLinkText: 'text1',
  brandInfoLinkTextLink1: 'text2' // and many more that I lose count
};

function loopthru() {
  var obj = {};

  Object.keys(contentAsset.custom)
    .filter(function (key) {
      return /^brandInfoLink(Text|Url).*/.test(key);
    })
    .forEach(function(key) {
      obj[key] = contentAsset.custom[key];
    });

  return obj;
}

snippet.log(JSON.stringify(loopthru()));
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

And here's a version with Lodash:

```js
var contentAsset = {};
contentAsset.custom = {
  brandInfoHeader: 'header',
  brandInfoLinkUrl: 'link1',
  brandInfoLinkUrl2: 'link2',
  brandInfoLinkText: 'text1',
  brandInfoLinkTextLink1: 'text2' // and many more that I lose count
};

function loopthru() {
  return _.pick(contentAsset.custom, function(val, key) {
    return /^brandInfoLink(Text|Url).*/.test(key);
  });
}

snippet.log(JSON.stringify(loopthru()));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```